# Dialog Fragment didn't close in Android while onBackPressed and touch outside dialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Here I am using androidx dialog fragment. dialog fragment didn't close while clicking the back button and outside the dialog. Can anyone help me with this, thanks in advance

```
    private var alertDialog: AlertDialog? = null
    private var alertDialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder? = null
    private var mainView: View? = null
    private var rcvBrowserList: RecyclerView? = null
    private lateinit var browserMenuPopupAdapter: BrowserMenuPopupAdapter
    val newList = mutableListOf<SubCategory>()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        alertDialogBuilder = activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }
        mainView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.layout_broswer_menu, null)

        alertDialogBuilder?.setView(mainView!!)
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder?.create()
        alertDialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)

        alertDialog?.window?.setDimAmount(0.7f)
        alertDialog?.setCancelable(true)
        alertDialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)

        alertDialog?.setOnKeyListener(DialogInterface.OnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
            ) {
                alertDialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
                return@OnKeyListener true
            }
            false
        })

        findView(mainView!!)
        return alertDialog as AlertDialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you implement setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true). This prevent your touch for closing alertdialog if you click outside box. Try for set false or delete that line.

Comment: did not not work for me I have remove line and make cancelable false also I try both